# C# to run cmd netsh

Tags: c#, process, lan, system.diagnostics, netsh

I am trying to create a c# form with 2 buttons.

```
btn1 = disable LAN
btn2 = enable LAN
```

I have never done something on this level before.

What I want to accomplish is when I click on btn1 I want to disabled the LAN, and btn to enable it again.

This is what I am testing:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ipconfig);
```

This runs, it runs the cmd and ipconfig I can actually see the IP display BUT...

This is the netsh command:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=DISABLED
```

If I run this via the console it works 100%

I want to use this command by clicking the button?

How do I go about getting this to work? Because I have tried this and does not work:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection " admin=DISABLED);
```

any help?

Comment: What if the connection isn't called `Local Area Connection`?

Comment: For my case it'll always be Local area connection

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("netsh.exe", "whatever you would need to write as parameters");
```

For instance, for a mobile broadband connection, I would start this connection with:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("netsh.exe", "mbn connect interface=\"Mobile broadband\" connmode=name name=\"NAME OF CONNECTION\"");
```

In the above example, you would be able to find the name of the connection by finding the connection in your typical network manager (in Windows 8, it's in the right-side slide-in network overview thing). This part is not really relevant to your question, though, but others might be interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/C netsh interface set interface name=\"Local Area Connection\" admin=DISABLED");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was fixed with this solution:

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "netsh interface set interface name=\"Local Area Connection\" admin=DISABLED");
```

With this method, the command is executed in PowerShell